# Different wireshark decode result for a same http2 frame?

Tags: wireshark, http2

I decode a same pcap file on different terminal both using wireshark. While I have different output.

```
    Stream: HEADERS, Stream ID: 1537, Length 7, 200 OK
        Length: 7
        Type: HEADERS (1)
        Flags: 0x04, End Headers
        0... .... .... .... .... .... .... .... = Reserved: 0x0
        .000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0110 0000 0001 = Stream Identifier: 1537
        [Pad Length: 0]
        Header Block Fragment: 88c00f0d023236
        [Header Length: 78]
        [Header Count: 3]
        Header: :status: 200 OK
        Header: content-type: application/json
        Header: content-length: 26
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7bW4.png)

I check the hex steam and index for second different header are the same. So what causes the different?

Comment: I don’t understand the question. What’s the same? What’s different?

Comment: hi, the same pcap file, the same version wireshark. Decode result different, one decode the second header as Header: content-type: application/json, and another decode as 
Header: :status: 503 Service Unavailable, i check the hex stream for this header, both 'c0'

Comment: At least one or more of the protocol preferences (TCP, HTTP, ...) are likely different.  Compare your preferences or diff your preferences files and you'll surely find that they're not identical.

Comment: They are identical references. But that reference results in different things at different times. It's the way HPACK for HTTP/2 works. See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP/2 header's are compressed with HPACK. This uses a number of techniques to compress the headers, including referencing to a predefined static table, using a dynamic table, and also using Huffman encoding instead of plain ASCII.

The [HPACK static table](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7541#appendix-A) has 61 commonly used headers and values. It's quicker to say "Use static entry 8", rather than `:status: 200`.

The dynamic table is an extension of the static table but is built up over the connection. So new headers seen for the first time are added to from index 62. It's a lot quicker to say "See header 62, that I sent you previously", than it is to say "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36" again, and again, and again

However the dynamic table is shifted along with each new header - that is, the next new header is added with index 62, and the old header in spot 62 now becomes 63. This allows the oldest headers to eventually drop off the table after they reach the maximum size.

All this means it's not unexpected that two header blocks decode to different values, as the dynamic table is constantly moving. In fact it would be rare for two HPACK headers to decode to the exact same thing (implying that either only static look ups were used, or the dynamic header had not changed between the two requests).

To prove this is the issue, let's decode this header block:

```
88c00f0d023236
```

We need to look at this in binary as HPACK doesn't always use discreet 8-bit blocks (especially when using Huffman encoding):

```
10001000110000000000111100001101000000100011001000110110
```

There's [various types of HPACK header fields](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7541#section-6):

We start with a `1` so we know the first header field is an [Indexed Header Field Representation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7541#section-6.1) so the next 7 bits give the index value (`0001000` or 8) which, as it's less than 62, is in the [HPACK static table](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7541#appendix-A) and looking that up we see it is `:status: 200`.

Next we have `11000000`, which is also an Indexed Header Field Representation (starts with a `1`) for index value `1000000` or 64. That is beyond the 61 pre-defined static headers so is in the dynamic table. As discussed above this will likely be different with each request. This is your `c0` value and so explains it. In the first request the dynamic table must have `content-type: application/json`, in position 64, while in the second it must have `status: 503` in position 64 (though one thing I don't understand is why the second example has two status codes?).

After that, just to show the next header is what's expected and that I'm not making all this up, we have `00001111...`. It begins with `0000` so it's a Literal Header Field Without Indexing (meaning this header should NOT be added to the dynamic table since it's not likely to be needed again). The next 4 digits are 1111 which is index 15 + the next 8 bits (`00001101` = 13), so it's header 15 + 13 = 29 which is in the static table as `content-length` (which is why it makes sense why they didn't add it to the table, since content-length values are likely to be highly variable between requests). Next we look at the value of this header (`00000010`). This starts with a `0` so we know it's not Huffman encoded and it is length 2. So we look at the next 2 octets which will be in ASCII encoding as not Huffman: `00110010` (or 50 in decimal), which looking up [an ASCII table](https://www.asciitable.com/) is the number `2`, and then `00110110` (or 54 in decimal) which is the number `6` in ASCII. So we end up with `content-length: 26`, which is indeed what we see.

So both examples start with `:status: 200` and end with `content-length: 26`, neither of which use the dynamic table, so they can be the same.

The thing that's different is the bit in the middle, and in both cases it refers to whatever is in dynamic table position number 64 at that time. And that can be different at different times. Hence different values for the same encoded HPACK header.